# Capture the highest value for each computers from the SQL table

Tags: sql

Need to pull the last step performed by each computer in a specific task sequence

Wrote one SQL query which pulls the status of the computer for a particular task sequence with all the steps it performed during the task sequence run. But it shows all the steps which the machine performed where my actual requirement is to get the last step for each machine.

```
Netbios_Name0   Step    ActionName  Last Status
Computer1   0     xyx             Failed
Computer1   1     xyz             Success
Computer1   2     yyy            Inprogres
Computer2   0     xzz             Waiting
Computer2   1     xxy             Failed
Computer3   0     xyz             Failed
Computer3   1     xxx            Accepted
Computer3   2     xzy             Failed
Computer3   3     xzz            Success
```

```
Select Netbios_name0
,Step
,ActionName
,Laststatus
from [v_R_System] System
join [vSMS_TaskSequenceExecutionStatus] TaskSequence 
On TaskSequence.ResourceID = System.ResourceID
where packageID like '%PackageID%'
```

The expected out is like,

```
Netbios_Name0   Step    ActionName  Last Status
Computer1   2   yyy          Inprogres
Computer2   1   xxy           Failed
Computer3   3   xzz           Success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have window functions available...

```
select Netbios_Name0,Step,ActionName,Last Status
from
  (
  select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by Netbios_name0 order by Step desc) as rn
  from MyTable t1
  ) x2
where x2.rn = 1
```